# ModalWindow with out address bar and title string

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

I have tried to create a new modal window.But it shows an address bar and title is shown as about:blank.The code is shown @ http://jsfiddle.net/visibleinvisibly/vhudmz5u/

```
<button id="mydiv" onclick="myFunction( )"> The content</button>
<script>
function myFunction() {  
 var childWin = window.open ("about:blank", "MyWindow", "height=150,width=200");
     childWin.document.body.innerHTML = "<span style='color:red'>Hello World!</span>";
}
</script>
```

I guess in IE11 we cant hide the addressbar.Please let me know if you have any idea as to how to set the title for the modal popup..

Thanks in advance
Alex

Comment: I don't think it's possible.

Comment: showModalDialog has been flagged as depreciated.
http://status.modern.ie/#showmodaldialog

For future proofing/interoperability you should use the jquery dialog plugin or create your own with popup divs.

Answer (score 0):

If you want total control over the modal window, it may be a better idea to create your own. The idea is to create a div (the 'modal window' box) and a greyed out background layer between your page and the created div. This [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ha2cjynv/) provides some code for that. It uses jQuery. The central function is:

```
function createModalBox(html,useCloser){
    var box = $('#modalbox').length
                ? $('#modalbox')
                : $('<div id="modalbox"></div>').appendTo('body');
    var back = $('#modalback').length
                ? $('#modalback')
                : $('<div id="modalback"/>').appendTo('body');
    box.html(html);
    if (useCloser){
        $('<div id="modalclose" class="closer"/>').appendTo(box).show();
    }
    back.show();
    setTimeout(function(){box.fadeIn(); center(box[0]);},100);
    if (!back.attr('data-handled')){
        var f = function(){
            $('#modalback, #modalbox').fadeOut();
            $('#modalbox').remove();
        };
        $('body').on('click','#modalclose',f);
        back.attr('data-handled', true);
    }
}
```